# How to use Case in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query

```
Select Id,DeviceId,TankCount,Tank1_Level,Tank2_Level,ReadTime from Table 



  Id  TankCount   DeviceId  Tank1_Level   Tank2_Level    ReadTime

   1    1           123            20         50         2014-11-07 14:39:33.277
   2    2           456            52         78         2014-11-07 14:39:33.277
   3    1           789            44         50         2014-11-07 14:39:33.277
```

Tank2_Level is 50 in all TankCount=1 rows.

I dont want display Tank2_Level when value equal to 50.

TankCount int,Tank1_Level int,Tank2_Level int.

```
Id  TankCount   DeviceId        Tank1_Level   Tank2_Level                   ReadTime

   1    1           123            20         null or empty         2014-11-07 14:39:33.277
   2    2           456            52         78                    2014-11-07 14:39:33.277
   3    1           789            44         null or empty         2014-11-07 14:39:33.277
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Id,
DeviceId,
TankCount,
Tank1_Level,
CASE WHEN Tank2_Level = '50' and TankCount != '2' 
     THEN NULL 
     ELSE Tank2_Level 
     END AS [Tank2_Level],
ReadTime 
FROM table
```

Comment: Tank2_Level can be equal to 50 when TankCount=2.

Answer (score 1):

Is `Tank2_Level` a number or a string?  Let me assume it is a number:

```
select <other columns>,
       (case when Tank2_Level = 50 
             then 'null or empty' 
             else cast(Tank2_Level as varchar(255))
        end) as Tank2_Level
from . . .;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id,
DeviceId,
TankCount,
Tank1_Level,
CASE WHEN TankCount = 1 AND Tank2_Level = '50' THEN NULL ELSE Tank2_Level END AS Tank2_Level,
ReadTime 
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id
    ,DeviceId
    ,TankCount
    ,Tank1_Level
    ,(CASE Tank2_Level WHEN 50 THEN NULL
        ELSE Tank2_Level END)
    ,ReadTime
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it by using IIF

```
Select 
      Id,
      DeviceId,
      TankCount,
      Tank1_Level,
      iif((Tank2_Level=50 and TankCount=1),null,Tank2_Level) as Tank2_Level,
      ReadTime
from Table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Tank2_Level = CASE WHEN TankCount >= 2 THEN Tank2_Level END
FROM Table
```